# Window is not showing any text

Tags: electron

I tried index.js with following lines:

```js
var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app;
var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

app.on('ready',function() {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width:800,
    height:600
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html/')
})
```

And index.html with:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> </title>
  </head>
  <body> hello </body>
</html>
```

But the window which gets popped is not showing hello in it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, you failed to construct the proper URL for loading `index.html`. You can work with string concatenation, however the most reliable way of handling paths is

using the [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width:800,
    height:600
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html/')
```

should be

```
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html')
```

(without `/` at the end)